# How to save data from screen to separated class and views in another screen in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter

My Issue is I can now save a random data in a list in separated class and show it on the same screen by click on flatbutton, but when I moved to the second screen that I want to review the same data from the list I got an error because the list is Empty!!

This's the Page that sends data to list and show it on flatbutton

```
    WordsSaved wordSaved = WordsSaved();
    TestMemory testMemory = TestMemory();

    class WordsCard extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
    _WordsCardState createState() => _WordsCardState();
    }

    class _WordsCardState extends State<WordsCard> {
  int i=0;
  int _random;
  int get random => _random;
  String word ;
  int numberOfWords = 5;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _random = Random().nextInt(arabicWords.length);

    double currentOpacity = 1;
    return
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body:
                  FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
                    onPressed: ()=> {
                      setState(() {
                        if(wordSaved.wordsSaved.length < numberOfWords)
                          {
                        wordSaved.wordsSaved.add(arabicWords[_random]);
                        i++;
                          }
                        else
                          {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => TestMemory()
                            ),
                            );
                            print('The Words are Finished');
                          }
                          },
                        ),
                    },
                    child:
                    AutoSizeText(
                      wordSaved.wordsSaved[i],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      maxLines: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
),
}
```

And This's The separate Class

```
class WordsSaved {

  WordsSaved({ this.word}) ;
  final String word;
  int _random;
  int get random => _random;

  List<String> wordsSaved = [];
}
```

and this's the sound screen that reviews the same data from a list

```
WordsSaved wordSaved = WordsSaved();

class TestMemory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestMemoryState createState() => _TestMemoryState();
}

class _TestMemoryState extends State<TestMemory> {

  int i=0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body:
             FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
                    onPressed: ()=> {
                      setState(() {

                      },
                      ),
                    },
                    child:
                    AutoSizeText(
                      wordSaved.wordsSaved[i],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      maxLines: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
)
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at the Get_It package (Singleton) for your word saved class.  Access word saved from the first screen to save the data.  Access word saved from the second screen to retrieve the data.  locator() is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, thank you for your question! You could use the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package to handle the state of the `WordsSaved` class throughout the different pages of your application. I have added a code sample below showing you how you could do this. You might like to take a look at the documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) if you haven't done so already for more information regarding how to handle state in a Flutter application.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) {
          return WordsSaved();
        },
      ),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WordsCard(),
    );
  }
}

class WordsSaved extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _wordsSaved = <String>[''];

  List<String> get wordsSaved => List.unmodifiable(_wordsSaved);

  void addWord(String word) {
    _wordsSaved.add(word);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeWord(String word) {
    _wordsSaved.remove(word);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class WordsCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WordsCardState createState() => _WordsCardState();
}

class _WordsCardState extends State<WordsCard> {
  final arabicWords = <String>[
    'Aamer',
    'Al-Abadi',
    'Abargil',
    'Abaza',
    'Abbar',
  ];

  int i = 0;
  int _random;
  int numberOfWords = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _random = Random().nextInt(arabicWords.length);

    final wordsSaved = context.watch<WordsSaved>();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
        onPressed: () {
          if (wordsSaved.wordsSaved.length < numberOfWords) {
            wordsSaved.addWord(arabicWords[_random]);

            setState(() {
              i++;
            });
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TestMemory(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Text(
          wordsSaved.wordsSaved[i],
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestMemory extends StatelessWidget {
  final i = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordsSaved = context.watch<WordsSaved>();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(
          wordsSaved.wordsSaved[i],
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```